# Value of property Configuration must be an object with String (or simple type) properties for Environment variable

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecr

I have an assignment where we need to parameterize an ECR URI as an environment variable. The output should be something like this:

```
914710628553.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/classweb
```

I've tried doing this as seen below:

```
"Configuration": {
"ProjectName": {"Ref": "AppBuildProject"},
"EnvironmentVariables":[{
    "Name": "REPOSITORY_URI",
    "Value": {
        "Fn::Sub": "${AWS::AccountId}.dkr.ecr.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/classweb_1"
    }}]
```

},

But when I do that I get the following error:

> Value of property Configuration must be an object with String (or simple type) properties

Answer (score 0):

`EnvironmentVariables` should be JSON **string**, as shown [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-CodeBuild.html#action-reference-CodeBuild-example):

```
"Configuration": {
"ProjectName": {"Ref": "AppBuildProject"},
"EnvironmentVariables": 
            {
                "Fn::Sub": "[{\"Name\":\"REPOSITORY_URI\", \"Value\":\"${AWS::AccountId}.dkr.ecr.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/classweb_1\"}]"
            }
```

The above is example, thus fixing the JSON string notation will still need to be done probably.